# Add sections to beamer presentation using rmarkdown and knitr

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to add section slides to a beamer presentation written in `rmarkdown` using the latex command `\section{}`. However, it gets inserted between a `\begin{frame}` & `\end{frame}` automatically during the conversion, which causes the compilation to fail. Is there any way to stop this happening so that the section slide can be added without having to manually edit the `tex` file?

Here is my `rmarkdown` code:

```
---
title: "Beamer presentation"
output: beamer_presentation
---

\section{Section one}
```

which gets converted to:

```
\title{Beamer presentation}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\section{Section one}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slides and section slides are both defined by markdown headings, a series of `#` character at the beggining of a line, the number of `#` indicating the hierarchical level of the title.

> By default [the level that defines frames] is the highest header level in the
>   hierarchy that is followed immediately by content, and not another
>   header, somewhere in the document.

All title of higher level than this one will become section titles.

From the [rmarkdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html#table-of-contents-and-slide-level) ; See also the [pandoc documentation on slideshows](http://pandoc.org/README.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc).

For instance :

```
# Section title

## Frame title

Frame content

### Subtitle inside a frame
```

Comment: I feel so dumb! Thank you @scoa :-)